# PlusSampleActivity an internal error occurred

Tags: android, google-plus

When I tried to run the PlusSampleActivity from the google plus SDK, I cannot sign in with google+ sign in button. It shows a toast "an internal error occurred".

I am pretty sure my package name is correct and SHA1 is correct too.

The keystore I used is correct. I am pretty sure, because I use that keystore to register facebook app, and it works.

Comment: Dont post sensitive information. Hiding your image, please censor it.